# Evaluating the integral $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi/2} (\cos^{5}x)\sin (7x)dx$?

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

I tried to expand $\sin(7x)$ into $\sin x,\cos x $ terms but integral is getting pretty lengthy and cumbersome , how do i approach in a simpler way ?

Comment: This looks nasty, how did you run into this monster?

Comment: @gt6989b just a casual class test , but wolfram gives a simple 1/6 as the answer .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Observe that $$\sin 7x = \sin 6x \cos x + \cos 6x \sin x,$$ hence $$\cos^5 x \sin 7x = \sin 6x \cos^6 x + \sin x \cos^5 x \cos 6x.$$  Now here is the tricky part:  if we let $u = \cos^6 x$, $v = \cos 6x$, we get $$u' = -6 \cos^5 x \sin x,$$ and $$v' = -6 \sin 6x.$$  So what does this suggest?

Comment: Oh nice i also smelled some relation between power 5 and inner 6's but the substitution disnt cross my mind , thank you so much.

Comment: Btw $u' = -6 \cos^5 x \sin x,$

Comment: @SujithZis Corrected.  Now just divide by $-6$ to get the required relationship.

Answer (score 2):

No need to do any clever thinking :)
Since
\begin{align*}
\cos^5(x)
&= \left( \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^5 \\
&= \frac{1}{32} \left[ \sum_{k=0}^{5} {5 \choose k} e^{kix}e^{-(5-k)ix}\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{32} \left[ \sum_{k=0}^{5} {5 \choose k} e^{(2k-5)ix}\right]
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\sin(7x)
&= \frac{1}{2i} \left(e^{7ix} - e^{-7ix}\right)
\end{align*}
we have
$$
\cos^5(x) \sin(7x) = \frac{1}{64i} \sum_{k=0}^5
{5 \choose k}  \left[ e^{(2k+2)ix} - e^{(2k-12)ix} \right]
$$
so
\begin{align*}
\int \cos^5(x) \sin(7x)
&= \frac{1}{64i} \sum_{k=0}^5
{5 \choose k}  \left[
\frac{e^{(2k+2)ix}}{(2k+2)i} - \frac{e^{(2k-12)ix}}{(2k-12)i} \right] \\
&= -\frac{1}{128} \sum_{k=0}^5
{5 \choose k}  \left[
\frac{e^{(2k+2)ix}}{k+1} + \frac{e^{(2k-12)ix}}{6-k}
\right].
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^5(x) \sin(7x)
&= -\frac{1}{128} \sum_{k=0}^5
{5 \choose k}  \left[
\frac{e^{(2k+2)i\pi/2} - 1}{k+1}
+ \frac{e^{(2k-12)i\pi/2} - 1}{6-k}
\right] \\
&= -\frac{1}{128} \sum_{k=0}^5
{5 \choose k}  \left[
\frac{(-1)^{k+1} - 1}{k+1}
+ \frac{(-1)^{k-6} - 1}{6-k}
\right] \\
&= -\frac{1}{128} \left[
\frac{-2 {5 \choose 0}}{0 + 1}
+ \frac{-2 {5 \choose 2}}{2 + 1}
+ \frac{-2 {5 \choose 4}}{4 + 1}
+ \frac{-2 {5 \choose 1}}{6 - 1}
+ \frac{-2 {5 \choose 3}}{6 - 3}
+ \frac{-2 {5 \choose 5}}{6 - 5}
\right] \\
&= \frac{4}{128} \left[
\frac{1}{1}
+ \frac{10}{3}
+ \frac{5}{5}
\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{32} \cdot \frac{16}{3} \\
&= \boxed{\frac{1}{6}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: But thats $\cos(hx) , sin(hx)$ formula right , i have seen this exponential forms but we haven't been taught to use it anywhere yet , but your answer is very much self-explanatory , thanks for the answer , its always fun when we are able to solve big questions in different ways

Answer (score 1):

$\int \cos^5x\sin7x dx = \int \cos^5x(\cos6x\sin x+\cos x\sin6x) dx = \int\cos6x\cos^5x\sin x+\cos^6x\sin6x dx$.

Let $u = \cos^6x$ and $v=\cos6x$ so that $du = -6\cos^5x\sin x dx$ and $dv = -6\sin6x$.
So the original integral becomes: $-\frac{1}{6}\int udv + vdu$
And we get $-\frac{1}{6}\cos^6x\cos6x$.
Applying limits then gives the answer of $\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Thanks thats a really nice substitution

Comment: But one negative sign will come outside right

Comment: Oops yeh. I dropped my negative sign.